# How to select spans that have a specific attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to manipulate spans that have the "email" attribute, this is my code:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span"),
    index, node, emailAttr;
for (index = 0; index < spans.length; ++index) {
    node = spans.item(index);
    emailAttr = node.getAttribute("email");
    if (emailAttr) {
        // Do something with `node` and `emailAttr`
    }
}
```

Everything goes well until the last if statement, it can find the spans but no result for spans that have the email attribute. What is wrong here?

This is part of the html code i'm trying to scan:

```
<span class="yP" email="nobody@mozilla.org">Mozilla Add-ons</span>
```

Note: i don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: There's also [`hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.hasAttribute) - maybe `getAttribute()` returns a truthy dummy value.

Comment: Also, use data attributes and the HTML5 doctype. Also, provide a jsFiddle.

Comment: hasAttribute returns the same thing..nothing

Comment: Works for me in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LJxRJ/ – are you sure you're calling this after the <span> exists in the DOM?

Comment: Also works when using `email` instead of `data-email`, and with the doctype set to HTML4 Strict: http://jsfiddle.net/LJxRJ/2/

Comment: @Inerdiae yes the spans are in the DOM. i can count them even.. there are 38

Comment: I always keep the [Browser compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) next to me when working with the DOM. Anyway, @Tom: you should always tell what browser you are using and try to provide a working example when it comes to things that could be due  to such incompatibilities.

Comment: @Inerdia the problem was with the index var. Instead of node = spans.item(index); i did node = spans[index]; and now it works

Answer (score 0):

There is no "email attribute". In HTML5, input elements can have an email type. However, HTML5 is not a standard, is not fully supported by any browser and most older browsers only support that part of it that is compatible with HTML 4.01 (which is the current HTML standard).

If you wish to be compliant with HTML5, then non-standard attributes should use a *data-* prefix so you should be using *data-email*.

To determine if an element has a particular attribute or not (as opposed to whether the attribute has a truthy value or not), you can consider the [hasAttribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-ElHasAttr) method. However, some browsers (e.g. IE < 9) don't support it and there is no viable work around (some have tried by parsing an element's outerHTML but I wouldn't suggest it). Also, you must use *getAttribute* to read the value because earlier versions of Firefox (and other browsers) do not create element properties for non-standard attributes.

One option for wider support is use a *data-email* attribute that always has a truthy value (i.e. anything other than an empty string). That way you can test with *getAttribute*.

An alternative is to use a class so that any element that should have the attribute also has the class, e.g.

```
<span class="... email ..." data-email="foo@bar.com">foo</span>
```